Threejs texture loaded in Ldraw object goes all black
I am trying to display a Ldraw object with a texture on the shape.
It works when I add material color but goes all black/random light color when trying to add a map material image. See my code:
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";
let texture = loader.load('images/texture.png');
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
});
model.traverse((child) => {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        console.log(child)
        // This WORKS
        // child.material.color.set(Math.random() * 0xffffff);

        // This goes to all black or other plain color
        child.material = material;

        child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide; // or THREE.FrontSide
        child.material.needsUpdate = true;

    }
});

scene.add(model);

After I run the code it shows this:

but I change to random colors:


A common root cause is missing texture coordinates. So please make sure the geometry of your meshes holds a uv attribute.
